# openstack create ports in the specified server

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I need use openstack command to create server port, and command like this.

```
$ openstack port create --disable-port-security --network test_net --device df5dae52-569d-48da-9e8d-fec6d56e2221 --device-owner compute:nova --enable test-p1
```

But when I show the port's detail,

```
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Field                   | Value                                                                                                                                                                          |
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| admin_state_up          | UP                                                                                                                                                                             |
| allowed_address_pairs   |                                                                                                                                                                                |
| binding_host_id         | worker-10                                                                                                                                                                      |
| binding_profile         |                                                                                                                                                                                |
| binding_vif_details     | bridge_name='br-int', connectivity='l2', datapath_type='system', ovs_hybrid_plug='False', port_filter='True'                                                                   |
| binding_vif_type        | ovs                                                                                                                                                                            |
| binding_vnic_type       | normal                                                                                                                                                                         |
| created_at              | 2021-12-21T09:09:19Z                                                                                                                                                           |
| data_plane_status       | None                                                                                                                                                                           |
| description             |                                                                                                                                                                                |
| device_id               | df5dae52-569d-48da-9e8d-fec6d56e2221                                                                                                                                           |
| device_owner            | compute:nova                                                                                                                                                                   |
| dns_assignment          | None                                                                                                                                                                           |
| dns_domain              | None                                                                                                                                                                           |
| dns_name                | None                                                                                                                                                                           |
| extra_dhcp_opts         |                                                                                                                                                                                |
| fixed_ips               |                                                                                                                                                                                |
| id                      | 3785e3de-2606-4ea3-8b3b-444302883f07                                                                                                                                           |
| location                | cloud='openstack_helm', project.domain_id=, project.domain_name='default', project.id='a9e3d71fc89147e7aadd28179c03df6c', project.name='admin', region_name='RegionOne', zone= |
| mac_address             | fa:16:3e:2e:9a:a5                                                                                                                                                              |
| name                    | jj-ctr-test-p1                                                                                                                                                                 |
| network_id              | 17e0c1c4-0048-4a33-a162-ef9cf52fb399                                                                                                                                           |
| port_security_enabled   | False                                                                                                                                                                          |
| project_id              | a9e3d71fc89147e7aadd28179c03df6c                                                                                                                                               |
| propagate_uplink_status | None                                                                                                                                                                           |
| qos_policy_id           | None                                                                                                                                                                           |
| resource_request        | None                                                                                                                                                                           |
| revision_number         | 3                                                                                                                                                                              |
| security_group_ids      |                                                                                                                                                                                |
| status                  | DOWN                                                                                                                                                                           |
| tags                    |                                                                                                                                                                                |
| trunk_details           | None                                                                                                                                                                           |
| updated_at              | 2021-12-21T09:09:51Z                                                                                                                                                           |
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I found that the port status is still down. when I login into the server, the port has not been attached into the server.
According to my knowledge, the "device" parameter will specify server id. But it seems doesn't work.

Comment: Do you use `openstack server add port` to bind the port to the instance?

Comment: when I try to execute `openstack server add port`, it shows `Port 8bc26ea5-6f24-4e49-96d8-dd13809c9dac is still in use. (HTTP 409) (Request-ID: req-f3ddd009-44b8-4237-900e-0803c208c908)`

Answer (score 0):

According to the help page in Victoria release and the output you provided the `--device` parameter specifies the port UUID (which you can choose), not the server UUID. Check your command and the line `device_id` from the output, they're the same. After you created the port you need to attach it to the server as @VictorLee already suggested.

Comment: As the port's details show, it seems that `id` is the port UUID intead of `device`. When I created a port and attached it into a server, I found `device` is the server's UUID after executed `openstack port show`

Comment: @qihang why not use this method `created a port and attached it into a server`?

Comment: @VictorLee I used the method as you said before, but as the number of ports increases, the speed of attach ports into a server becomes slower and slower. When the number of ports of all servers exceeds 2500, it will take 1 minute to add a port on average. Therefore, I want to specify a  server when creating a port to test whether it can improve efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

In my practice, the best way also is `create port and attache it to server`.

To achieve your requirement, maybe you should execute **`hard reboot`** the instance or `server stop` and then `start` it, before that you should make sure it could get the new port `ip` info by `server list` or `server show`.

It works for me by obey the above method. Sometime there will not update the new ip info to server immediately, I could reboot the instance and it will update it but not attach new interface or you could wait a period that server info would update automatically by `nova-compute` period task. And then I have to **`hard reboot`** the instance, after that the instance will attach the new interface.

I guess the `port create` command only execute method like `create_port` in `ml2 plugin` or others, but not execute the `port_update` or `port_bind` methods like `server add port` command. The more detail we should dive into the neutron source code and the business logic flow about that.

[image]

Comment: I am making use of openstack to simulate the network behavior of the data center. It takes a long time for my device to reboot, which will reduce the speed of building the whole network. Anyway, thank you for your contribution. I am seeking ways to improve efficiency from neutron source code. If I solve this problem, I will share the solution under this comment. Thanks, VictorLee.